# how to set the ctx fill position on line doughnut label

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

current doughnut graph look,
[doughnut chart first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGFd4.png) 
in the above graph, the floating circle is not aligned properly in line.
expected how the graph should be,[doughnut chart second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWewE.png)

in the second image, the floating circle is properly set in line. how can I achieve that?

bleow is code example ->
https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-sunset-y494et?file=/index.html

thanks.

Comment: Don't post links to images, images of code, or, even worse, links to images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just have to add the thickness of the circle to your calculation, in the `afterDraw` function and than it should work

```
         ... 
         ctx.arc(
            (arc.round.radius + arc.round.thickness) * Math.sin(endAngle),
            (arc.round.radius + arc.round.thickness) * Math.cos(endAngle),
            arc.round.thickness,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI
          );
          ...
```

Here is the [link to to the forked codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-glade-3xwi0f?file=/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. exactly what I want.

Comment: @dei_sudo Great to here, if it worked for you please consider accepting my answer with the green checkmark. Thank you